# How would a @monitors like decorator look like in Python?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, python-decorators

I am writing a python script, in which a function should be monitored by another function. The monitor would run for the duration of the monitored function. I couldn't find any documentation on proper implementation of such functionality, nor could I find a library that does something like that.

The logic goes something along the lines of:

```py
def monitor():
    """
    This function would run in a different thread while the
    `some_cool_function` function is running.
    
    In this example, this would execute 5 times.
    
    This function should not be blocking:
    >>> some_cool_function()
        hi from monitor!
    this should be instantaneous!
        hi from monitor!
        ...
    done!
    """
    print("    hi from monitor!")
    time.sleep(2)


@monitors(monitor)
def some_cool_function():
    """
    @monitors decorator should run the defined function
    in a thread.
    
    This is blocking.
    :return: 
    """
    print("this should be instantaneous!")
    time.sleep(10)
    print("done!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_cool_function()
```

Comment: just to clarify, so you want both these functions to be ran in different threads without blocking one and another yes?

Comment: No, I want `some_cool_function` to spawn the `monitor` in another thread, and run itself in the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

It'd look something like:

```
from threading import Event, Thread

def monitors(monitor_func):
    def decorator(decorated_func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            done = Event()
            def run_monitor():
                while not done.is_set():
                    monitor_func()
            Thread(target=run_monitor).start()
            result = decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)
            done.set()
            return result
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

Note that `wrapped` is the thing that actually executes when you call `some_cool_function`, so that's where you need to launch your `monitor_func` thread.

Applying that decorator to modified versions of your test functions:

```
def monitor():
    print("monitor start")
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print("monitor done")


@monitors(monitor)
def some_cool_function():
    print("some_cool_function start")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("some_cool_function done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_cool_function()
    print("all done!")
```

we get the output:

```
monitor start
some_cool_function start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
some_cool_function done
all done!
monitor done
```

Note that the last `monitor done` prints *after* `all done!` because the monitor thread finishes after the main thread.

If you want to make sure that `some_cool_function` doesn't return until the last invocation of `monitor` is done, change this:

```
            Thread(target=run_monitor).start()
            result = decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)
            done.set()
            return result
```

to do a `Thread.join` before returning:

```
            thread = Thread(target=run_monitor)
            thread.start()
            result = decorated_func(*args, **kwargs)
            done.set()
            thread.join()
            return result
```

which changes the output to:

```
monitor start
some_cool_function start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
monitor done
monitor start
some_cool_function done
monitor done
all done!
```

Comment: Yes, this does run in a thread - however, the wrapped `monitor_func` runs only once - it should run for the duration of the `decorated_func` lifetime.

Comment: ah, I missed that in your docstring and it wasn't part of your actual question.

Comment: Will edit the question. My bad.

Comment: Updated answer.  It's not really a big change, you just need a little helper that runs `monitor_func` in a loop until an `Event` is set.

Comment: yes  - just that this code, like the question itself, have no way of actually interacting with  running function. i.e. all such a code could monitor would be the effects of outputs generated by the decorated function. I mean: the code is correct, the usefulness of the proposed task to start with not so much.